# Prevent duplicates using INNER JOIN and ON with this SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Please refer to below SQL query. I am trying to create a simple activity feed that will match the person who is on record in the `updated_by` and/or `created_by` fields (whichever is newer) in a tasks table with their profile picture in a users table. This query works, except I get duplicates when the two fields have different users because in the ON clause both elements of the OR statement will return true as there is always a `created_by` that will match someone in the users table - I cannot figure out how to limit this to just one when both fields are filled with different users. I've tried adding more CASE WHENs to the ON clause but there is no if/else logic to it so it just defaults to both being true again and returns the same results.

(Note that I need to maintain the ability to limit results in the WHERE clause with status items which are passed in as variable, the query is contained within a PHP function.)

Ideas?

```
SELECT tasks.*, users.profile_pic, 
CASE WHEN tasks.updated_at > tasks.created_at 
THEN tasks.updated_at 
ELSE tasks.created_at 
END AS recent_activity 
FROM tasks 
INNER JOIN users 
ON tasks.updated_by = users.name OR tasks.created_by = users.name 
WHERE status <> :status1 AND status <> :status2 
ORDER BY recent_activity DESC LIMIT 10'
```

Comment: would a created_by ever be newer than an updated_by?

Comment: Use the same CASE statement in the ON clause as you do in the SELECT clause.

Comment: @Uueerdo Encompassing all the tasks, yes created items can be newer than updated ones as new ones will be made often. For individual tasks, updated time stamp will always be newer than created.

Comment: @seibzehn yeah, I meant in  the same record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emulate a lot of "if" logic with OR and AND like so:

```
ON (tasks.updated_at > tasks.created_at AND tasks.updated_by = users.name)
   OR (tasks.updated_at <= tasks.created_at AND tasks.created_by = users.name)
```

or use logic similar to what you have in the select:

```
ON CASE 
      WHEN tasks.updated_at > tasks.created_at 
      THEN tasks.updated_by 
      ELSE tasks.created_by
      END = users.name
```

Alternatively *(since OR and more complicated comparisons like the above pretty much rule out any benefits of indexing)*, you could join to the users table twice and pick the prioritized value in the select:

```
SELECT tasks.*
  , CASE WHEN tasks.updated_at > tasks.created_at 
    THEN uu.profile_pic
    ELSE cu.profile_pic
  END AS recent_profile_pic 
  , CASE WHEN tasks.updated_at > tasks.created_at 
    THEN uu.name 
    ELSE cu.name 
  END AS recent_activity 
FROM tasks
LEFT JOIN users AS uu ON tasks.updated_by = uu.name 
INNER JOIN users AS cu ON tasks.created_by = cu.name 
WHERE status <> :status1 AND status <> :status2 
ORDER BY recent_activity DESC LIMIT 10
```

*This is assuming all the fields you used that did not specify the table they were a part of were from `tasks` and the extra join will not cause ambiguities.*

Comment: You might need to use a LEFT JOIN for the "updating user", if it's possible that `updated_by` is NULL.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Ah, good catch, I just did a quick cut/paste/re-alias on my first pass.

Comment: With approriate indexes the join-twice-solution should be the fastest one. Also if `created_at` is never older than `updatet_at` you can select `tasks.updated_at AS recent_profile_pic`. And if `updated_by` is allways NULL when no uptade has been made, you can select `COALESCE(uu.profile_pic, cu.profile_pic)`. That would make the code look less complex.

Comment: Just playing with the first two examples I am already seeing the results I was after. I'm going to test the join twice method next. Many thanks for the ideas @Uueerdo, and also Paul Spiegel for your input.

Comment: @seibzehn also, if it is a possibility to change how you write your data (in code, or trigger), you could just make the initial value for updated_by to the same value as created_by when the data is inserted; then you wouldn't actually need to even look at created_by for these kinds of queries.

Comment: @Uueerdo Wow, wish I had thought of that from the beginning, its so simple! I'm going to update my insert queries to make this happen. Thanks again!